# Select a range in Pandas based on the same value in 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, range

I am trying to select a range within a  data frame based on the values. I have logic for what i am trying to implement in excel and i just need to translate it into a python script. I need to return a range of rows from where the value in starting where Column A value is and ending where Column B has that same value. Example below:

| index | A | B | output range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | dsdfsdf |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |
| 4 | quwfi |  |  |
| 5 |  | dsdfsdf | 0:5 |
| 6 |  | quwfi | 4:6 |

One thing to note the value in Column B will always be lower down the list than Column A

So far I have tried to just grab the index of Column A and put it on the row in output range for Column B using,

```
df['output range'] = np.where(df['B'] != "", (df.index[df['A'] == df.at[df['B']].value]))
```

This gives me a ValueError: Invalid call for scalar access (getting)!

Removing the `np.where` portion of it does not change the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the required behavior:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['dsdfsdf','','','','quwfi','',''],'B': ['','','','','','dsdfsdf','quwfi']})
def get_range(x):
  if x != '':
    first_index = df[df['A'] == x].index.values[0]
    current_index = df[df['B'] ==x].index.values[0]
    return f"{first_index}:{current_index}"
  return ''
df['output range']= df['B'].apply(get_range)
df
```